# Getting data back on Html.ListBoxFor post in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, html.listboxfor

It seems all the examples I can find use a ViewModel for some reason, so a MVC and not MVVM answer is what I'm looking for :)

Controller

```
List<PermOptions> have = new List<PermOptions>();
List<PermOptions> nothave = new List<PermOptions>();

...populate the lists here...

var set = new PermissionSet
        {
            ExtId = extid,
            HaveList = have,
            NotHaveList = nothave
        };

return View(set);
```

View

```
@model path.to.model.PermissionSet
@{
    var NotHave = new MultiSelectList(Model.NotHaveList, "Id", "Role");
 }

@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.NotHaveList, NotHave, new { @size = "30", id = "possible" });    

@{
    var Have = new MultiSelectList(@Model.HaveList, "Id", "Role");
 }

 @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.HaveList, Have, new { @size = "30", id = "have" });
```

Everything works just fine displaying the initial lists and moving items, but when I submit the form the ListBoxFors are part of to the Post action, PermissionSet.HaveList and PermissionSet.NotHaveList are empty with a zero count.  Thinking it was a select issue or format of return issue, I added javascript to select all the items in both boxes, and in the browser debug pane I can see that there are values in the submitted Form data that match up to various option values for NotHave and Have, but if in the Post action, I make a call to ViewData["NotHave"], it is also reporting empty.

What do I need to do to get the list of items in each ListBoxFor in my Post controller, preferrably as part of PermissionSet?